# How can I convert a png to base64 and then use it in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an image list and I want it to be in a HTML export. So the way that I need to achieve this is converting to base64. But I didn't find valuable information on how to transform the image to base64 and how to use it in HTML. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the image use Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
And  embed the result in the IMG Tag like this

```
src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,imagestring"
```